# Testing react redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, enzyme

I have a react component which can result in one of two redirects being rendered, such as:

```js
render () {
  if(condition) {
    return <Redirect to={'page1'} />
  } else {
    return <Redirect to={'page2'} />
  }
}
```

In the enzyme test, I have found out how to test that a redirect is being rendered:

```js
expect(page.find('Redirect').length).toEqual(1)
```

However I am not sure how to configure the test so that I can test which of the redirects is being rendered. According to the Enzyme [find](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/selector.md) docs it is not possible to use find to locate a tag along with an attribute, which leads me to believe I am going about this in the wrong way.

Comment: Have you tried the snapshot? You would create to tests (one for each condition) that will create a snapshot. Check the snapshot is fine and it should be sufficient:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
expect(page.containsMatchingElement(<Redirect to="page1" />)).toEqual(true)
```

Which would allow you to assert that the correct redirect is rendered under the correct circumstance

Alternatively, if there are more props being added to the component when it is mounted, you could always do something like:

```
page.find('Redirect').debug()
```

And match the attribute manually with RegExp.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize attributes could be passed within an element on that matcher.